# @InjectView doesn't works on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, view, code-injection

I'm building an Android app using Android Studio.
I decided to use an external library to draw a custom progress bar.

I've a problem with ButterKnife injection's library. Pratically, when I launch the app, I receive this exception:

```
Process: com.robertot.timereport, PID: 16449
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.robertot.timereport/com.robertot.timereport.pages.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.robertot.timereport/com.robertot.timereport.pages.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject views for com.robertot.timereport.pages.MainActivity@64b1fd48
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
```

Instead, this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    @InjectView(R.id.google_progress)
    GoogleProgressBar googleProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);   // CRASH HERE

        //....
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `R.layout.activity_main` contains a GoogleProgressBar? If so, are you sure that the ProgressBar's id is `google_progress`? Also make sure that you aren't missing a `+`.

Comment: Yes!! This is the problem!! the google_progress was in a custom action bar layout that I initialized next the code in main post. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `@InjectView`s has correct type.

I've used `ImageView` instead of `LinearLayout`.